# Using Magento 2 Rest API to filter on product visibility

Tags: rest-api, visibility

I want to retrieve only products that are listed as visible in both catalog and search, yet can't find any confirmed way to do this.   The obvious solution I was hoping would work (shown below) returns no results...

> /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=visibility&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Specify the **`field name,value`** and **`condition type`** in your REST API Query along with the pageSize parameter.

> rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=visibility&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=20

Refer the official documentation below for clarity

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/performing-searches.html

Comment: That still doesn't work im afraid.   I did have other parameters in my rest query but ive now removed them. If I use just the filter above I get null results.     How can I confirm if "visibility" is actually the correct field name?, I can't find that in the documentation.

Comment: Go to the Swagger page and  https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/  and check the catalogProductRepositoryV1 GET /v1/Products section

Comment: So via swagger I have CATALOGPRODUCTRENDERLISTV1 and that doesn't have visibility or anything similar.  There are no other interfaces to the products listed.  On the magento documentation I can see under catalogProductRepositoryV1 there is "visibility".  How do I alter the interface I have in my install to make this property available ?

Comment: Please see my answer updated. You need to specify the pageSize parameter otherwise you will get null results. i checked this in my localhost it works fine.